# Can you "compact" a SQLite database on-the-fly once it's deployed on an android device?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

After creating my first SQLite database for use in an Android app I found that it seriously needed compacting after just a few 'drop table' operations etc. Then after reading some of the SQLite documentation it made sense as to why - that unlike most databases, SQLite uses variable length records to store data very efficiently. But this suggests to me that in everyday use it would need compacting all the time to keep it at optimum space-efficiency - especially on an Android device where internal memory is at a premium.

So can this be done programmatically from your Android app once it's deployed on a device? And is it common practice, or wise,  to do this frequently? I ask this because I don't know what sort of memory the internal memory of an Android device is - if it's flash memory like the SD card then constantly changing the database (or indeed any files) would not be good for its lifespan, would it not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Freed space is reused by any new data that is inserted later.
(And this has nothing to do with variable-length records.)

If you have removed lots of data and *know* that the free space will not be reused in the near future, you could execute the [VACUUM](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html) command.

Doing this very often might affect the flash lifespan.
However, if you do this often, you regularly *do* use the space in the database file before it is freed, so it would not make sense to compact the file only for it to be expanded shortly later.
Therefore, flash lifespan considerations are irrelevant for the question when to execute VACUUM.

Comment: Thank you, that definitely looks like it will keep the database size in check. But do you happen to know whether the internal memory of a phone is suited to running this function often?

Comment: Thank you for your update. I don't understand your second point as I'm very new to this, but I'll take your word for it that there's nothing to worry about regarding flash lifespan. Hopefully I'll understand it better when I've been doing this a bit longer.